# Update package version (openocd) in buildroot

Tags: buildroot, openocd

I'm working in a project that uses buildroot-2012.11 to generate a Linux image for an embedded system.

I need to configure openocd for a JTAG debugger that uses an FTDI chip (FT2232D).

I realized that this buildroot version integrate openocd-0.5.0 and the latest openocd release is 0.9.0. I'm interested in updating to this version since I want to use **ftdi** interface driver instead of **ft2232** (deprecated).

I tried to accomplish that by modifying /package/openocd/openocd.mk on the lines:

```
OPENOCD_VERSION:=0.9.0

OPENOCD_CONF_OPT += --enable-ftdi
```

The new openocd files where downloaded successfully but when it tries to install it and apply *openocd-0001-fix-cross-compilation-host-libsub-was-used-before.patch* I got:

```
Applying openocd-0001-fix-cross-compilation-host-libsub-was-used-before.patch using patch: 
can't find file to patch at input line 17
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|From 3728c4af7f6303ccedab56ec220797f8f290580e Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
|From: Jean-Christophe PLAGNIOL-VILLARD <plagnioj@jcrosoft.com>
|Date: Wed, 10 Aug 2011 00:17:29 +0800
|Subject: [PATCH] fix cross compilation: host libsub was used before
|
|tested in buildroot
|
|Signed-off-by: Jean-Christophe PLAGNIOL-VILLARD <plagnioj@jcrosoft.com>
|---
| configure.in |    7 +++++--
| 1 files changed, 5 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
|
|diff --git a/configure.in b/configure.in
|index dfa1e8f..cfe2218 100644
|--- a/configure.in
|+++ b/configure.in
--------------------------
File to patch: configure.in
configure.in: No such file or directory
```

If I skipped the patch the building process stop and I'm not able to generate the images.

I've doing some research on the internet and I couldn't find how to do this correctly.

Maybe one obvious solution could be updating the buildroot version but since there is a lot of other people development with the current version I'm not in a position of taking that decision right now.

I'll do appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your Buildroot release. 2015.08 already has OpenOCD 0.8.0 and it should be trivial to update to 0.9.0. Plus you will benefit from the numerous improvements and updates that have been made between 2012.11 and 2015.08.

Comment: Finally a fellow help me putting together a patch. Upgrading Buildroot is a good solution but it implies a fair bit of work to get all the board profiles working and tested.